# Azure cloudblockblobs storage use full 4MB for files under that size?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am just wondering, If I have a file which is just 2MB for example. Will it uses the whole 4MB chunk or will it just use 2 MB?

I uploaded a 33MB Picture to the stroage, is that divided into 4MB chunks?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, a block blob in Azure can be of 200GB in size however you can only upload a blob up to 64 MB without breaking it into chunks. Any blob bigger than 64 MB must be broken into chunks and then these chunks should be uploaded. Any file less than 64 MB can also be uploaded by breaking into chunks as well. However the maximum size of the chunk can be 4MB. Please note that this is the maximum size. Minimum size of the chunk would be 1 Byte and you can pick any number between 1 Byte and 4 MB to be your chunk size.

Now if you're uploading a 2 MB file, you can decide to upload it without breaking into chunk or can upload it by breaking into chunks. Since the file size is 2 MB, the maximum size of the chunk in this case would be 2 MB (i.e. you're uploading the file by breaking it into 1 chunk of 2 MB size).

If you're uploading a 33 MB file, again if you have good Internet connectivity you can upload that file without breaking it into chunk because its size is less than 64 MB limit but it would be better if you split it into chunks. Now assuming you decided to break this file into chunks for 4 MB each, then in that case there will be 9 chunks. 8 chunks would be of 4 MB each and the last chunk would be of 1 MB (4 MB * 8 + 1 MB * 1 = 33 MB).

Comment: Exactly. :) It totally depends on the chunk size specified by you.

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu So I changed, the limit to 100MB from the `web.config` in the asp.net mvc... if I upload a 100 MB, would it automatically break down into chunks? or would I need to do extra coding? thanks

Comment: It depends on which method you're calling. Could you tell me?